# Is asking "Why learn language x" off topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm looking for justification for learning a particular language that doesn't seem useful in the rest of the industries.

Is asking a question about why learn language x on topic, and seeking advantages?

Comment: Depending on the language, you might stir up a pretty interesting conversation in chat. And, remember, not many study esoteric programming languages for their usefulness, they just want to have some fun.

Comment: @TinyTim, well the concern is am I waisting my time in an industry that wants me to primarily focus on this language that might not be useful in the future. I do like learning new languages, and think it'd be great experience especially one that's OOP…but "will it harm my future dependency in the industry" is what goes through my head.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's off topic on Stack Overflow because it's too broad and it's opinion based.

See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [Why are some questions marked "on hold"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

As noted in the comments, it's also [off topic on Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Questions about what language, technology, or project one should take up next are off topic on Programmers, as they can only attract subjective opinions for answers. There are too many individual factors behind the question to create answers that will have lasting value.

Comment: Side note, the same would apply for Programmers.StackExchange as on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to being opinion-based, it would also be a duplicate many times over. How many different ways can the question really be asked?

Also, I think it's misleading to suggest that it matters what language you learn next. Programming has much less to do with what language you're using than a beginner would expect.